# Testing a Sinatra application that uses session

Tags: testing, session, sinatra, rack

How to test Sinatra application which is using session?

```
get "/", {}, {'rack.session' =>  { 'foo' => 'blah' } }
```

This code doesn't work for me, I have 'enable :sessions' in my app.

Comment: Why don't you use session[:foo] = 'bla' ? Check out the Sinatra documentation

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm in the same mess, and I tried your way as well as the proposed solutions below. Nothing works.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the problem is actually to have `enable :sessions` activated.

You have to deactivate this setting in order to be available to overwrite the *session*.

The solution could be:

```
# my_test.rb (first line, or at least before you require your 'my_app.rb')
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

# my_app.rb (your sinatra application)
enable :sessions  unless test?

# my_test.rb (in your test block)
get '/', {}, 'rack.session' => { :key => 'value' }
```

In the other hand to be able to check any *session* change that the *action* is expected to do we can send not a *hash* to the *rack.session* but a *pointer to a hash* so we can check after the *action* call if the *hash* has changed:

```
# my_test.rb (in your test block)
session = {}
get '/', {}, 'rack.session' => session
assert_equal 'value', session[:key]
```

Comment: This did not work for me, using Sinatra 1.2. I realise this answer is 7 months old, did you find some alternate solution?

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this problem and the solution is simply the order of requiring the files, so @fguillen was correct. At the top of your spec, make sure you require rack/test before your sinatra app, so at a minimum, this should get you started:

```
# in myapp_spec.rb
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'
require 'myapp'

it "should set the session params" do
  get 'users/current/projects', {}, 'rack.session' => {:user =>'1234'}
end

# in myapp.rb

enable :sessions

get 'users/current/projects' do
  p env['rack.session']
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Like Philip suggested, it would work better to manually set the session variable before the get request.

```
session[:foo] = 'blah'
get "/"
```

Comment: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'session'`

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured it out by monkey patching `Rack::Test::Session`:

https://gist.github.com/troelskn/5047135