# How to make Sinatra sessions persist across POSTs in tests?

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack

In the following code from Learn Ruby the Hard Way : https://gist.github.com/1696733 the session seems to disappear after going through the 'post' in **tests** (run `ruby test_gothonweb.rb` to see what I mean). If I actually visit the site with my browser everything works correctly, but I would like to be able to test the site without visiting every page. What are the possible reasons for the sessions disappearing in tests?

There are a few questions coming close to this problem, but most of them are solved by not using shotgun. I am **not** using `shotgun`. I am just using regular `ruby`.

Versions:

- ruby: 1.9.2
- sinatra : 1.3.2
- rack: <strike>1.4.0</strike> 1.4.1
- rack-test: 0.6.1

**EDIT**

I am also disabling the sessions while testing as per http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra - the first test using sessions with GET does work in that case (but not the POST one).

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with rack 1.4.0. Update the gem to 1.4.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the rack gem to 1.4.1, but the error persists. Other clues?

Comment: sorry, didn't see the gist. You're not enabling sessions when running tests. By saying unless test? you're skipping the session option. Try removing the unless tests?

Comment: Yeah I am doing this based on the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402808/how-to-test-sinatra-app-using-session and http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra . If I remove `unless test?` the first test fails (get) - but it works if I disable session in test.