# Unable to change Sessions in Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

I am currently working with a Sinatra app, and struggling to re-set my session variable. This is not your typical "my session disappeared" issue - the problem is I can't alter or change the sessions I have set. Maybe this is a dumb question, and they aren't supposed to change, but that seems like less of a value to my project, as I need to set and then later change a session variable. General code concept below -

```
get '/' do 
    session[:data] = {:key, 'default'}
  p session[:data] #{"key","default"}
end 

post '/:data' do
  p params[:data] #"data"
  session[:data] = {:key, params[:data]}
end

get '/anotherpage' do
  p session[:data] #{"key","default"} as result, even after posting to /:data
end
```

The session[:data] persists across various routes no problem, but I cannot update, remove, change, anything. Any ideas?

Comment: this is the idiomatic way a session should work. sure you are passing through the post method and actually changing something?

Comment: Yes - I can verify that the data is being posted properly, however I can not get the session variable to update.  It always returns the initial set value.

Comment: try this example: http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions

Comment: That is how I got to where I am.  From there, it's a matter of changing the session variable, which doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: It may be important to mention, that I set the session on initial page load, and the posts are done via ajax.

Comment: sure that your session cookie get's sent via ajax?

Comment: Yes, check that the Set-Cookie header is part of the response.

Comment: I think I am running into this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402808/how-to-test-sinatra-app-using-session

Comment: I added the gem, and things work perfectly.

Comment: If you solve your problem, please add a answer and accept it. :)